# Javascript: Trying to refactor so many IF statements in order to display pictures continuously

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, promise, refactoring

I am trying to display a slideshow of images from an array using a promise.  On load, I want the page to display the first image, then the next, and so on.  When it's at the last picture index, I want the first picture to display and the code to keep repeating.

The class '.show-image' is visibility: visible.  I have the first picture index classed as '.show-image', but the rest are hidden.

Is there a cleaner way of writing this without having so many IF statements?

```
let pictures= document.querySelectorAll(".moving-pics img");

async function changePicture() {
     
    for (let x=0; x < pictures.length; x++) {
           
       await new Promise(resolve => {
             setTimeout(() => {
                
                 if (!pictures[x - 1]) {
                     pictures[pictures.length - 1].classList.remove('show-image');
                 }

                 if (pictures[x - 1] && pictures[x - 1].classList.contains('show-image')) {
                     pictures[x - 1].classList.remove('show-image');

                 }
      
                 pictures[x].classList.add('show-image');
                 if (!pictures[x + 1]) {

                     resolve();
                     changePicture();
                    
                 }
                 resolve()
             }, 3000)
        });                  
    }
}
```

Comment: Forget the multiple ifs, why does this logic need to use `Promise`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep the index being iterated over in a persistent outer variable, you can use it to identify the last element with the `show-image`. Use optional chaining so the first iteration doesn't throw. To move on to the next image, use modulo to keep things concise.

I'd also just use `setTimeout`, if you have an individual call of `changePicture` change a single picture, I don't think there's any need for the Promise anymore:

```
let i = -1;
function changePicture() {
    pictures[i]?.classList.remove('show-image');
    i = (i + 1) % pictures.length;
    pictures[i].classList.add('show-image');
    setTimeout(changePicture, 3000);
}
```

Comment: would this work if they need to have it continually reset at the end of the list and start over again?

Comment: Yes, the `i = (i + 1) % pictures.length;` loops back to the beginning once the last picture is reached.

Comment: `x % x == 0`, so once you hit the length of the array, which is beyond the n - 1 bounds, you go back to 0 @RicardoAlvveroa